# VBA script to set background color if cell is not empty

Tags: excel, vba

Just started with VBA in Excel 2016..
I'm trying to figure out a script to give non empty cells a background color
This is what I got:

```
If Range("a3:g8").Value = "" Then
  Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
End If
```

But it's not working. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you considered just using conditional formatting - no coding necessary.

Comment: You are targeting blank cells, not 'non empty cells'.

Comment: @Dragonthoughts It is part of a bigger macro, this is the last piece not working.

Answer (score 0):

You can define the cells into a single variable and loop through. See below code

```
Dim rng As Range, cell As Range
Set rng = Range("a3:g8")

For Each cell In rng
    If cell.Value = "" Then
        cell.Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)

    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

To target blank cells,

```
With Range("a3:g8")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A3=TEXT(,)")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
    end with
End With
```

To target non empty cells,

```
With Range("a3:g8")
    .FormatConditions.Delete
    with .FormatConditions.Add(Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=A3<>=TEXT(,)")
        .Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
    end with
End With
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to do is compare the value of entire range with "" which will throw a type mismatch error. You will have to check the value of each cell one by one or try the below code which uses a simple excel formula:

```
 If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Range("A3:G8")) = 0 Then
       Range("A3:G8").Interior.Color = RGB(222, 244, 180)
 Else
       MsgBox "Range has some value"
 End If
```